# Linker adds the path to library in the dynamic section instead of its name

Tags: gcc, ld

I have this command to link an executable

```
/usr/bin/c++ myexe.cpp.o -o myexe \
  ../mylib/libmylib.so ../libstring/libstring.so
```

Then running

```
objdump --private-headers myexe
```

gives me

```
Dynamic Section:
  NEEDED               libmylib.so
  NEEDED               ../libstring/libstring.so
```

How come one of the libs is referenced only by its name in the Dynamic Section and the other `libstring.so` is reference by its relative path as passed with the linker command? As you can see the two libs are passed in the same manner.

I don't have control over building `libstring.so`, it is an external library.

The only meaningful difference when running `objdump --privatge-headers` on the libs is that `libstring.so` has this section:

```
Version definitions:
1 0x01 0x060cd9ff bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/labm8/labm8/cpp/libstring.so
```

Comment: What's the current directory? Is `../mylib/` the same as `.` in this case?

Comment: No, it is another directory. The current directory is `myexe`.